# Properly configure image segmentation on QGIS (Segmentation / MeanShift)

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, image-segmentation, otb-applications

I'm trying to perform remote sensing on georeferenced historical satellite images (taken from Google Earth), using the segmentation algorithm from OTB.

In the parameters of the Segmentation algorithm, depending on what spatial radius and range radius I specify, the result will vary.

**Is there a way to know, according to the image characteristics, which values are required to execute the best segmentation?**

I have read somewhere that I could execute the ComputeImageStatistics algorithm, to get the information I need. I can't find where I read it.

For my current image, the execution of this algorithm give me this result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FeatureStatistics>
    <Statistic name="mean">
        <StatisticVector value="30.3281" />
        <StatisticVector value="40.098" />
        <StatisticVector value="38.0882" />
    </Statistic>
    <Statistic name="min">
        <StatisticVector value="0" />
        <StatisticVector value="0" />
        <StatisticVector value="0" />
    </Statistic>
    <Statistic name="max">
        <StatisticVector value="255" />
        <StatisticVector value="255" />
        <StatisticVector value="255" />
    </Statistic>
    <Statistic name="stddev">
        <StatisticVector value="30.9288" />
        <StatisticVector value="40.2171" />
        <StatisticVector value="36.3203" />
    </Statistic>
</FeatureStatistics>
```

But I don't know how to analyze it.

---

Here is the satellite image I'm trying to process:

[image: Original]

Here is a comparison between two different configurations:

> spatial radius: 35
> range radius: 3

[image: 35-3]

> spatial radius: 30
> range radius: 3

[image: 30-3]

> spatial radius: 20
> range radius: 4

[image: 20-4]

> spatial radius: 10
> range radius: 5

[image: 10-5]

The segmentation isn't properly done in this area

As you can see, the last attempt presented above gave a good result. But I don't know why and I would like to know **how can I identify the proper values that must be entered into "spatial radius" and "range radius"** before doing so many attempts (21 in my case).

I have edited this post to focus on one issue.

Comment: I'm searching for a way to avoid creating them, or, at least, deleting them automatically. But, the more I'm searching, the more I think the quality of the basemap is playing an important role. Since I cannot have a better satellite imagery, I'm trying to combine it with a DEM. In this particular situation, the altitude can help to remove the polygons that are not valid.

Comment: I have edited my first post. The main question is about how to configure properly the segmentation algorithm. I should not have mentioned invalid polygons, because it is related to how I trained the algorithm and not about segmentation itself.